# get height of content in iframe use iframe resizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe-resizer

I use an iframe to embed one site in my application and use iframe resizer library.

```
<iframe id="iframeContainer" class="iframeContainer" src="mysite.com" width="100%" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

and code script

```
iFrameResize({
  log:true,
  autoResize: true,
  resizeFrom: 'child',
  sizeWidth:false,
  checkOrigin:false,
  minWidth: 1200,,
  heightCalculationMethod: "max"
});
```

I want get `height` content of `mysite.com` after load parent page, but I've thought of a way.

Comment: you can't access inside of iframe when it is cross domain

Answer (score 0):

You can use resizeCallback for this.

```
var iFrameHeight;

iFrameResize({
  log:true,
  minWidth: 1200,
  heightCalculationMethod: "max",
  resizeCallback: function(iFrameData) {
    iFrameHeight = iFrameData.height;
  }
});
```